# Java : Is it possible to know JVM instance used by a web server

Tags: java

I have 4 webservers of a Single Web application running in production .

Is there anyway by which i can know that all of them sharing/using  a same JVM ??

Is it possible to know any such information ??

By the way we are  using 4 instances of Jetty Web servers for scalability controlled by a Load Balancer in front  and JDK 1.6 version .

Comment: single web app means single JVM wil be used, in share.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if there is 4 instances of Jetty then you have 4 JVMs running, these 4 instances cannot be sharing a JVM.

Comment: Ohh. I don't think so since only one web app is running.

Comment: Single web app deployed across a cluster of 4 jetty servers with a load balancer in the front... Clustering is a standard practice just because its the same web app doesn't mean it's the same JVM

Comment: Ok Thanks for claryfying is there any concept in Jetty that these 4 web server instances will share a Single JVM ??

Comment: Not possible, each instance of jetty is running as a difference process and each process is a different JVM therefore you can never have 4 instances of jetty running with a single JVM. Do you know what a JVM is? Are you mistaken perhaps JVM with the version of Java that is running?

Comment: Process cant be JVM, JVM is the layer, between actual os, and the output of JIT. So, there should be a single instance of JVM, though I am not expert in server apps.

Comment: @jeet: Depends on what you think makes a JVM. If you start a text editor 2 times, and open a different document in each, would you say that the two documents 'share the same text editor'? They are using the same binaries, but run in different processes. If someone talks about 'sharing a VM', they usually mean 'sharing the running process', because sharing the binaries is trivial. +1 for the answer.